# Give the employee(fname and lname) that make the most money in each dept

Tags: each, currency

```
SELECT max(salary), dept
FROM Employees
GROUP BY dept;
```

How to add fname and lname without the errors? If I add them in group by, I no longer get the max salary.

Comment: Also I have to make it a subquery

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in SQL Server...  You need a subquery that returns the max salary for each department, then join that back to the employee table to figure out which employee has that salary for that department:

```
SELECT D.Dept, D.MaxSalary, Employees.FName, Employees.LName
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary, Dept
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY dept
) D
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Employees.Dept = D.Dept
AND Employees.Salary = D.MaxSalary
```

Comment: Thanks david, I sadly do not know/understand what I am doing.